# CicuitMaker Project about a parking counter

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design

I am trying to simulate in Circuitmaker a 2-floor parking counter that every time a car enters the parking lot it increments the counter of the first or second floor and ask him if he wants to wash the car or not. Then of course decrement when the car leaves the parking. The limit for each parking floor is 9 cars. it first increments the upper one till it reaches 9 and stop then continue to the lower one till it reaches the same value and stops.

How can I decremented in this circuit by using another switch Pulse that knows which displays it's in right now and decrement 1 by 1? like if I start decrementing from the lower display and it reaches 0 it goes to the upper one and decrement it to. I am using as the picture I sent you 2 ripple counters and a bunch of logic gates.

[image]

Comment: What if the car enters the lower level? Your explanation is that it will increment the upper counter and that doesn't sound right. Surely you need an independent counter for each floor?

Comment: So the assumption is that all entering cars go to the upper floor first, until it is filled up? Then how do you know which floor the car came from when leaving?